# How to create a process as a another user without a password in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, process, uac

I'm trying to create something in C# like sudo for Linux.
I found a way to run the process as a different user using the password, but I want to do this without the password.

Also, my C# software is running as Administrator and has passed UAC.

My currently Code:

```cs
static void CreateProcessAsUser(string name, string path, SecureString password)
{
    Process proc = new Process();

    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    proc.StartInfo.UserName = name;
    proc.StartInfo.Password = password;

    proc.Start();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Let's call the user your software is trying to run a process as user2. Does user2's account have a password, and you're trying to get your code to run a process without knowing that password? Or does user2 not have a password at all?

Comment: It is the former. User2 has password certification. The process was running with Administrator authority, so I thought it was possible, but isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows is not Linux, so you cannot expect a feature just like sudo.

No matter which programming language (C# or C++) you use, deep down inside you need to call [`RunProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) (no, not your current code as yours is far too simple for the purpose) to initialize a process running as another user account. This API in turn wants a user token, which you either create with user credentials (aka password) via [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera), or clone from an existing token via [`DuplicateToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-duplicatetoken).

So the only way to avoid password is to find a valid user token already on this machine (once that user logs on).

You might wonder what applications use such a complex mechanism and why. One example is your antivirus software, whose main component is a Windows service running as administrator. This service detects who logs on to the machine and then launches a tray icon application. (That's the perfect time to duplicate a user token and create a process as that user.)

If your goal is not to cover similar scenarios, I wonder whether you should continue on this path.

Comment: In addition to Lex's answer, here's further reading to help explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net